# Query regarding arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var arr=[1,2,3,[4,5],6,[7,8,9]],x,j;
for(x in arr)
   for(j in arr[x])
       console.log(arr[x][j]);
```

I want to print 1,2,3,...,9 but the above code prints 4,5,7,8,9.

Comment: What Kyle Dodge said, or you could flatten the array using, e.g., `_.flatten()` in underscore/lodash.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, you want to console to log 1 through 9. The way you currently have it, its only going to print the arrays within your array - that is why you are only getting 4,5,7,8,9.

What you could do is check to see if the value is an array in your first loop - if it is, iterate over it and print the values. If it is not, simply print the value.

```
if(arr[x].constructor === Array) {
    //loop over the array and print out the values
    for (j in arr[x]) {
      console.log(arr[x][j])
    }
} else {
    //print out the plain value
    console.log(arr[x])
}
```

Here is a pen to show the result: http://codepen.io/kyledodge/pen/zGwPBo

Another option is to use recursion. You could do something like this:

```
var printArrayValue = function(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].constructor === Array) {
      //if this an array, call this function again with the value
      printArrayValue(array[i]);
    } else {
      //print the value
      console.log(array[i]);
    }
  }
}

printArrayValue(arr);
```

Here is a pen to show the result: http://codepen.io/kyledodge/pen/VLbrPX

Answer (score 1):

I think "join" is enough:

```
console.log(arr.join());
```

Answer (score 0):

Coerce each element to array:

```
var arr=[1,2,3,[4,5],6,[7,8,9]],x,j;
for(x in arr) {
    var arr2 = [].concat(arr[x]);
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    for(j in arr2)
       console.log(arr2[j]);
}
```

This works because `concat` takes either an array or a single value.